# Buddhist holy water

Tags: theravada

I have seen it on Buddhist temples in Thailand, I would like to understand more about this tradition: Where does it come from, if it dates from the time of the Buddha etc

thanks!

Comment: The answer to this question contains a reference to water in temples. Not a full explanation though. http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/7255/significance-of-three-customs-involving-string

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic mindset of theravada buddhism. We donate flowers, water, food,etc. for Buddha then we believe these things are holy things.Because these are for Buddha.We pray Buddha statue is not praying the statue that created by someone.We pray Buddha statue is represent our respect for Buddha knowledge and teachings.The holy water is not come from Buddha's age but we donate this water for Buddha(in Buddhist temple) and we believe this water is holy.It's only mindset.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I was referring to. Holy water was given to lay people by the monks, I'm not asking about the offerings